# Pandas and lists efficiency problem? Script takes too long

Tags: python, pandas, list, performance

I'm kind of new to python and pandas. I have a csv with aroun 100k rows, with only three interest columns:

| idd | date | prod |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 201601 | 1000 |
| 1 | 200605 | 2000 |
| 2 | 200102 | 1500 |
| 2 | 200903 | 1200 |
| 3 | ....... . | ....... |

I needed to group by idd, order by date (year) and then transpose the 'prod column so the first existing 'prod' value for each idd sorted by date ends up in the first column after idd, dropping the date value. In my example it would be this:

| idd | '1' | '2' | '3' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000 | 1000 | ... |
| 2 | 1500 | 1200 | ... |
| 3 | ... | ..... | ... |

I also filtered for idds which have more than "nrows" reported values, since I am not interested in idds that have lesser than a certain value. Since I have read that recorring groups made by groupby is not efficient, I made a list of names resulting of groupby and made the queries to the original dataframe, but nevertheless it takes too long (like 5 minutes) to run. Maybe I am doing something wrong? I tried to use objects at minimum, loop using iloc and for loops to increase efficiency and use list of names instead of "get_group" but maybe I am missing something. Here is my code:

```
nrows = 36
for name in grouped_df.groups.keys():
    for i in range(0, len(origin_df[origin_df.idd == name]['idd'])):

        if len(origin_df[origin_df.idd == name]['idd']) >= nrows:

            aux_df = origin_df[origin_df.idd == name]
            aux_df.sort_values(by=['date'], inplace=True)
            idd = name
            prod = aux_df.iloc[i, 1]
            new_df.loc[idd, i + 1] = prod
            new_df.loc[idd, 'idd'] = idpozo
```

This is my first question in this page, so if I made some styling errors please forgive me, and all suggestions are welcome!!! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.set_index(['idd', df.groupby('idd').cumcount() + 1])['prod'].unstack()
```

Output:

```
        1     2
idd            
1    1000  2000
2    1500  1200
```

Comment: That's great and super fast. I don't have a clue what the cumcount method does but I will investigate. The only caveat is that now 'idd' column is the index column and I would like to be the first column and don't move it to index, but I think I can manage to change it. Thank you!!! :)

Comment: Add .reset_index() to move that idd out of the index into columns.

Comment: Yes, I did. Man I cannot thank you enough. Not only I speeded up the process A LOT, but I also learned new methods. Thank you very much!!!